# Binding 'Delimiter' In Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I know you can use the `export-csv` feature to quickly export data to a csv file, but I keep getting an error of

> Export-csv: can not bind parameter 'Delimiter'. 
> Can nnot convert value "C:\Test' to type System.Char
> Error: String must be exactly one character long

This is my powershell syntax - and the data I want to export can have `\` or a `-` in it

```
$info = (@'Foxtrot')
foreach ($in in $info)
{
  $Dir = "C:\$in"
  export-csv C:\$in.csv $Dir
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that '$in' has spaces in the name?

Comment: @rrirower - no, if I do a Write-Host command to see the output of $in it produces C:\Foxtrot no spaces

Comment: So `C:\$in.csv` becomes `C:\C:\Foxtrot.csv` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the parameter names as the `-Delimiter` is the second parameter e.g.

```
Export-Csv -Path "C:\$in.csv" -InputObject $Dir
```

Comment: Please provide the full solution including the original question